# VS Code Python 3 doesn't actually create text file but it can still read from it

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I've been using the stock Python IDLE for a while which has worked great, but I just downloaded VS Code and whilst it's a clear upgrade, I've noticed an issue with it, particularly with databases and text files.

I created a simple program which writes to a text file and then reads from it:

```
def writeText():
    textFile = open("test.txt","w")
    textFile.write("test")
    textFile.close()
def readText():
    textFile = open("test.txt","r")
    store = textFile.readlines()
    print(store)

writeText()
readText()
```

The first procedure should create 'test.txt' and write to it, whilst the second procedure will print the lines from it.

When I run the program in VS Code, the output is correct. However, when I check my file directory, there is no text file called 'test.txt', and yet it was able to output correctly.

When I run this code in the Python IDLE, it creates the text file correctly.

Can anyone help me get to the bottom of this? Thanks

Comment: I am not a VS pro, but if the `print` works, I am guessing the file was created somewhere - perhaps search the project directory. Note also you forget to close the file in `readText` - consider using `with open(...` in general.

Comment: @kabanus Yeah I've searched the directory, and it's not there. When I ran the code with the Python IDLE, it created the text file in the directory. I'm not sure where else it could be but I'll try looking in the VS Code directory.

Comment: Try to print `os.getcwd() ` before opening the file - and see where it is supposedly being created by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried with this setup in launch.json

```
    {
        "name": "Python: Current File (Integrated Terminal)",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/abc.py",
        "console": "integratedTerminal"
    },
```

where `abc.py` is the file you have written, and it worked fine and created the file as expected:

[image]

Comment: Sorry if this sounds very stupid, I'm very new to VS Code, like a few hours new, but do I have to edit the launch.json file with that? Thanks

Comment: You can read instructions from here https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging or you can directly edit that file inside `<your project>/.vscode/launch.json` . If this answer helps you to solve your problem, then please mark this as [accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: Alright looks like this worked! Thank you very much. I just put in 'workspaceFolder' without the specific file name and it seemed to work for any file in my directory. If I was running a python file in another folder, would I need to create and edit a launch.json for that folder too?

Comment: I don't think so. `workspaceFolder` is the root of your project/workspace. So you can point relative path to that python file in different folder to run it.

Comment: Ah yes, I understand now. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try to run it with the Option 'Run Current File in Interactive Window'.
It is worked for me.

You can find it here:

[image]