# Storing input from user to txt file on Mac

Tags: python

So basically what this code is supposed to do is to be a login page. It asks wether if the user has an account or not ( in my case the user doesn't have an account ). The user creates an account ( this part works ) but the user info is not saved in the txt file. I looked at other sites and youtube videos that explain this topic, but none of them work. Visual Studio doesn't give me an error but when I open the txt file, the info is not shown. Also, I work on a mac ( don't know if it will matter ).

```
def main_menu():
    OPTION = input("Do you have an account? (yes/no)\n")
    if OPTION == "yes":
        login()
    if OPTION == "no":
        register()

def register():
    USERNAME = input("Create your username: \n")
    PASSWORD = input("Create your password: \n")
    database = open("databse.txt", "w")
    database.write(USERNAME)
    database.write(PASSWORD)
    database.close()
    PASSWORD_CHECK = input("Confirm your password: \n")
    if PASSWORD_CHECK != PASSWORD:
        print("Your passwords do not match. Try again. \n")
        register()
    if PASSWORD_CHECK == PASSWORD:
        print("You have successfully created an account! Welcome!")
        # another menu here

def login():
    pass
    
main_menu()
```

Comment: It works as expected for me. Maybe take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53065217/vs-code-python-3-doesnt-actually-create-text-file-but-it-can-still-read-from-it)

Comment: It doesn't work but idk maybe its about the mac and that type of stuff. Even though, thanks a lot!