# No text file created in VS Code

Tags: python-3.x

I have tried creating a text file on VS Code using "w" mode but was not able to create one. When I tried doing it on PyCharm, it worked. Here's my code.

```
file = open("test.txt", "w")
file.write("some text")
file.close()
```

Comment: Not quite sure why this is happening as it is working fine for me. Can you share more details on how you are executing your file and if there is an error. Also, make sure you are saving your file before running.

Comment: Can you share some more details? Maybe some error you are getting, what commands are you trying to run in VSCode, etc. These things generally let us evaluate and understand the steps you are running and would help the community to help you in a better way.

Comment: Sometimes, you can get confused by the location at which it is creating file, check if the file is created somewhere where you haven't searched for it, like in the base directory of the project -OR- click in the file-explorer section of vscode and type this filename (it'll search for file there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VS Code Python 3 doesn't actually create text file but it can still read from it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53065217/vs-code-python-3-doesnt-actually-create-text-file-but-it-can-still-read-from-it)

Comment: It is totally working fine for me in VS Code. Can you share some more details regarding the errors you are getting?

Comment: In line with other comments, my suggestion is to define an absolute path where you'll be sure to search on for your new file.

Answer (score 0):

A similar question already has been answered here.

[VS Code Python 3 doesn't actually create text file but it can still read from it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53065217/vs-code-python-3-doesnt-actually-create-text-file-but-it-can-still-read-from-it)

Comment: I don't know how to do it. Can you help me?

Comment: @Samridh you shouldn't answer with a link that one day may be archivied or not accessible. Signal the answer as a possible duplicate instead.